# bootstrap 4 mobile toggle not working

Tags: jquery, mobile, bootstrap-4

> I have a working version of bootstrap 3 mobile nav, however I am trying 
>   to incorporate bootstrap 4. Using local versions of most files for testing 
>   purposes. I believe I included everything necessary, however toggle on 
>   mobile not working.  Jquery before all other js. thank you!

```
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<header> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-faded" role="navigation">

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse id="nav-content">

<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Project</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>    
</header>
<!--Core JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing double quote... `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">`

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse id="nav-content">`

should be

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">`

Make sure you close your double quotes (using any code editor should tell you about that unclosed double quotes.)

```html
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous"> JS, Popper, and jQuery
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-faded" role="navigation">

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id=" nav-content ">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link " href="# ">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link " href="# ">Project</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!--Core JS -->
  <script type="text/javascript " src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js "></script>
  <script type="text/javascript " src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js ">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript " src="assets/js/bootstrap.js "></script>

</body>

</html>
```